# jest mock: Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I want unit test this method (similar and inspired by [How to use Jest to test file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686077/how-to-use-jest-to-test-file-download)):

```js
export const download = (file, filename) => {
  FileSaver.saveAs(file,filename);
};
```

And this is the test:

```js
import { download } from "../../../utils/methods/utils";
import FileSaver from "file-saver";
import { item } from "../../__mocks__/responses/export"

describe("Test download", () => {
  it("Can handle download", () => {
    jest.mock("file-saver", () => ({
      saveAs: jest.fn()
    }));
    download(item.file, "test.xls");
    expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

But I get

```bash
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]

   9 |     }));
  10 |     download(item.file, "test.xls");
> 11 |     expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
     |                              ^
  12 |   });
  13 | });
  14 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/utils/methods/download.test.js:11:30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with [SpyOn a mocked jest module not spying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809648/spyon-a-mocked-jest-module-not-spying-properly).

Issue was a small timeout.

```js
it("Can handle download", () => {
    jest.mock("file-saver", () => ({
      saveAs: jest.fn()
    }));
    global.Blob = function (content, options) {
      return { content, options };
    };
    download(item.file, "test.xls");
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toBeCalled();
      done();
    }, 10000);
  });
```